# Hiding godaddy domain info from whois e.g. domain tools

Tags: domain, domain-name, whois

Does the protection that they offer work, in that the user's details are hidden?
Would appreciate if you could post an example of a protected domain name.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I managed to find a godaddy domain name that is protected. Here it is: http://whois.domaintools.com/best-widgets.com

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27083/hiding-whois-information-on-godaddy-registered-domains

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a Domains By Proxy registration ala GoDaddy at DomainTools:

```
Registrant:    Domains by Proxy, Inc. 
DomainsByProxy.com    15111 N. Hayden
Rd., Ste 160, PMB 353    Scottsdale,
Arizona 85260    United States
```

(for my registration of [hadeanllc.com](http://whois.domaintools.com/hadeanllc.com))

Answer (score 0):

It works to keep WHOIS users out. But if law enforcement or a court wants to find you they can order your registrar to disclose your details. Here is a sample output:

```
Administrative Contact:
Domain Discreet
ATTN: (removed).com
Rua Dr. Brito Camara, n 20, 1
Funchal, Madeira 9000-039
PT
Phone: 1-902-7495331
Email: 5f298ac10ac001654505b@domaindiscreet.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are directly allowed to manage your domain by godaddy then there must be an option to hide this information...